# Mongodb connecting to a database with old data when connecting through mongo --host

Tags: mongodb, web-applications, database

I have a instance running mongodb. I have used a config file while starting the database using mongod -f mongod.conf. I can connect to this mongodb instance from my application server instance. Recently, due to a software upgrade I had to restart the system. After that, I have been facing the following issue:

When I connect to the mongodb instance using mongo from the database instance(locally), it connects me to the proper database with the latest data. But, when I try to connect it from application server instance using mongo --host "ip_address", it is connecting to the same database but it showing the data which is some days old. I needed to know what the issue is and how will I be able to fetch the latest data which is residing in the database from the application server instance.

Comment: Sounds like you have two instances running. Check your configuration again. Or just check the running processes. There should be more than one `mongod` in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing it out, there were 2 mongod processes running.

Comment: There actually is almost "half an answer" in here, as if you setup bind on "0.0.0.0" for one server instance and another on a specific IP, say "192.1.1.1", then the one with the "0" mask bind will "attempt" to connect to all available interfaces. **However**, if the other address was already "explicitly" bound, then "that" process will get that address and the "0" mask will get all the others available. Hence the trap you appear to have fallen into, by possibly altering your new configuration when a first attempt  failed to bind. Borders on off-topic for a programming site though.